# I try to solve the error (%matplotlib inline). The error message is as follows.

Tags: matplotlib, inline, backend

UnknownBackend: No event loop integration for inline. Supported event loops are : qt,qt4,qt5,.......

What's wrong with my Ipython?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. It will be easier for us to help you.

Comment: Where exactly did you type in `%matplotlib inline`? Which version of IPython are you using on which system? Are you using the QT version of IPython?